# Functions and variables disappearing of scope when using package

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, oop

In the document class, I got the following code:

```
package {
...
public class Main extends Sprite {
  public function Main(){
    ...
    model:IModel = new Model();
    controller:IController = new Controller(model);
    var controls:CompositeView = new Controls(model,controller)
    //Accessing controls.x provokes 1202: Access of undefined property x in package view
   }
  }
}
```

Where class `CompositeView` is a extension of `Component` which in turn extends Sprite.

Component:

```
package view
{
....
  public class Component extends Sprite
  {
  ...
  }
}
```

CompositeView:

```
package view
{
....
  public class CompositeView extends Component
  {
  ...
  }
}
```

Controls:

```
package view
{
....
  public class Controls extends CompositeView
  {
  ...
  }
}
```

But unfortunately, when I try to access `controls.x` I get a undefined property error.

Changing the package for all classes to the same name fixed this issue. E.g use `package` for everything instead of `package` and `package.view`.

What can be done in Actionscript to keep code organization and avoid this issue ?

**Problem solved:** var controls was used as a package name, changing name of the variable solved.